# Error compiling Function templates with C++

Tags: c++, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

I'm getting some errors in gcc and clang that I'm not familiar with. First off, here's the code in question.

WaypointTree.h:

```
class WaypointTree {

 private:
  Waypoint *head = nullptr;
  Waypoint *current = nullptr;
  template<class Function>
    void each_recur(Waypoint *current, Function f);

 public:
  template<class Function>
    void foreach(Function f);
  void add(Waypoint *wp, Waypoint *parent = nullptr);
  bool isLast(Waypoint *wp);
  Waypoint *next();
  Waypoint *getHead() { return head; }
  void reverse() {}
};
```

WaypointTree.cpp:

```
. . .

template<class Function>
void WaypointTree::foreach(Function f) {
  each_recur(head, f);
}

. . .
```

Flock.cpp:

. . .

```
_waypoints->foreach([] (Waypoint *wp) {
        glPushMatrix(); {
          glTranslatef(wp->getX(), wp->getY(), wp->getZ());
          glutSolidSphere(0.02, 5, 5);
        } glPopMatrix();
      });
```

. . .

With clang, I get the following warning:

```
lib/WaypointTree.h:17:7: warning: function 'WaypointTree::foreach<<lambda at lib/Flock.cpp:128:22> >' has internal linkage but is not defined
        void foreach(Function f);
             ^
lib/Flock.cpp:128:14: note: used here
        _waypoints->foreach([] (Waypoint *wp) {
                    ^
```

Followed by the following linker error:

```
lib/Flock.cpp:128: error: undefined reference to 'void WaypointTree::foreach<Flock::render(std::vector<Boid*, std::allocator<Boid*> >)::$_3>(Flock::render(std::vector<Boid*, std::all
ocator<Boid*> >)::$_3)'
```

With gcc I get only the following error :

```
lib/WaypointTree.h:17:7: error: ‘void WaypointTree::foreach(Function) [with Function = Flock::render(std::vector<Boid*>)::<lambda(Waypoint*)>]’, declared using local type ‘Flock::ren
der(std::vector<Boid*>)::<lambda(Waypoint*)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

I'm not really sure where to begin debugging this, but it seems to be related to the templates and the lambdas.

Comment: yes, it seems it is somewhat duplicated, now that answers have come in. However, the errors I was getting aren't mentioned in the other question. The other question presupposes that templates have to be implemented in the header file, whereas when asking my question, I had no idea about this restriction.

Comment: There are a _lot_ of questions like yours on this site. Giving you a link explaining _why_ you can't do what you're doing seems more instructive than just telling you "move the templates to the headers".

Comment: no, that makes sense. And I don't mind if the question is closed. I just spent a lot of time googling those errors (especially the clang one, that may have been my mistake) and didn't come up with anything mentioning this particular restriction. I feel that perhaps the question would be helpful even if it has been covered before since it's not an "exact" duplicate. I don't know if that's enough to not close it though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to implement your template functions in the .h file, not in the .cpp

[Here's some further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 2):

The compiler needs the definition in `WaypointTree.cpp` in order to generate the code for `_waypoints->foreach([] (Waypoint *wp)`. So you must either include your cpp as well or define `foreach` in your header file.